# Manually calculate the standard error for instrumental variable in R

Tags: r, variance, standard-error, instrumental-variables

I am working on a project that need to use instrumental variable.

I use the *ivreg* package and train on the *CigarettesSW* dataset from the *AER* package.

I follow the training from this site :
https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/12-1-TIVEWASRAASI.html

As you can see you  you don't have the same variance if you do it manually or automatically

```
cig_ivreg <- ivreg(log(packs) ~ log(rprice) | salestax, data = c1995)
```

Here the result with ivreg (automatic):

```
coeftest(cig_ivreg, vcov = vcovHC, type = "HC1")
#> t test of coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept)  9.71988    1.52832  6.3598 8.346e-08 ***
#> log(rprice) -1.08359    0.31892 -3.3977  0.001411 ** 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

The result if you do it manually :

```
cig_s2 <- lm(log(c1995$packs) ~ lcigp_pred)
coeftest(cig_s2, vcov = vcovHC)
#> t test of coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)  
#> (Intercept)  9.71988    1.70304  5.7074 7.932e-07 ***
#> lcigp_pred  -1.08359    0.35563 -3.0469  0.003822 ** 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

I'm trying to calculate the variance manually :

I follow this formula :
[image]

and this one :
[image]

Here is my code :

```
n <- 48

SST_x <- n*var(c1995$rprice)

# calculate R2x,y
reg <- summary(cig_s1)$r.squared

# calculate sigmasquare

var_pop_u <- (sum(cig_s2$residuals^2))/(n-2)
var_iv <- var_pop_u/(SST_x*reg)
```

9.10 * 10^-6

The result

```
v <- sqrt(var_iv)*100
```

0.30179

If someone could tell where I'm wrong.